# Bayesian GLM in R using inverse gaussian family

Tags: r, bayesglm

I am trying to fit a bayesian glm model to my data assuming an inverse family of distribution and `link=(identity)`. I am getting the following message:

```
Error in if (iter > 1 & abs(state$dev - devold)/(0.1 + abs(state$dev)) <  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting an error message as my code works for `family =gaussian` and `link=identity`.

Comment: You need to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).